# css themes for software not websites?

Tags: css

Are there any websites which has css themes for softwares instead of website.
For website there are many such sites.

I know many of you would say just copy the css from the web app you like or use/tweak the website css, but I was just curious.

Comment: What do u mean by css for softwares???

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.terrainformatica.com/htmlayout/main.whtm

Comment: @kvijayhari  suppose i am writing a phpmyadmin kind of software and I don't want to get into the css/theme part. Then can i get the css and and the related documentations which I can share with my coders.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about online applications, then you should be creating a css for them too.. There are no specific templates available for them.

Here are two which i've came across,

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/free-admin-template-for-web-applications/

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/admin-templates-professional-xhtml-back-end-template/

sample at http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/file/admin-template/index.html

I would suggest to download any css of any of the online application which almost matches your app, and then make changes... :(

To get css of any applications u like, use [web developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/) to view and download css files..